# Zend Framework globals file

Tags: zend-framework, registry, global-variables, configuration-files

I want to include a file with a list of global variables that are accessable everywhere in my zend framework application. It however needs to be easely adjustable by someone not very familiar with php or coding. The problem is that i don't really have much of a clue on how best to approach this.

There are options like using Zend_Registry, another config.ini file or just using standard defines.

What is the best practice in this case? If possible an example would be great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Zend_Registry` and a config file. You should keep non-class constants to a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

In one of my applications, I use a class named MyApp_Constants:

```
class MyApp_Constants{
 const SOME_CONSTANT1 = 1;
 const SOME_CONSTANT2 = 2;
 //...
}
```

I then access these variables anywhere in my code with the line:

```
MyApp_Constants::SOME_CONSTANT1;
```

Makes it easy for anyone to modify those values.